# How would I transfer a large amount of data to a MySQL server in one value?

Tags: php, mysql, data-transfer, large-data

I am making a PHP script which uploads a very large amount of data to a MySQL server. I do not have administrator rights for the MySQL server, so I can not change the maximum packet size, but I want to be able to transfer at least one Gigabyte of data to a single value on the server.

Because I am limited to the packet size max of the MySQL server, I am unable to transfer a large amount of data. Is there some keyword in MySQL for adding onto a value? If so, I could transfer the data in segments of the maximum amount of data the packets could be.

I have not found anything like this so far.

Is there some strategy I could use to store large (1 GB or more) amounts of data in a single MySQL value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the concat mysql method and UPDATE the data

```
UPDATE `table` SET `table`.`data` = concat(`table`.`data`, '$input') 
  WHERE `table`.`id` = $id;
```

Comment: I'll try that out when I can access the db!